# South Korean Visa for Research Conference

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-korea

I am an Indian passport holder, living in the United States. I have to travel to South Korea for a research conference. I want to know how can I apply for a visa for South Korea from the US. I tried searching for information here (http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/application/index.jsp?menu=m_40_10), however most of the links are not opening and throwing security error messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When looking up for visa issuance, it makes sense to search for Embassy/Consulate in your country. This is because the visa issuance procedure is a very low level detail, and often has country-specific requirements. MOFA web site usually covers high level things falling under "International affairs".

Most countries have more than one Consulate in the USA, and each Consulate usually only accepts applications from certain states. [Here are Republic of Korea consular missions in the USA](http://usa-atlanta.mofa.go.kr/english/am/usa-atlanta/mission/consular/index.jsp) explaining which state they cover. They only list phones and no web sites - google them.

And for example, [visa issuance page for Atlanta Consulate General](http://usa-atlanta.mofa.go.kr/english/am/usa-atlanta/visa/issuance/index.jsp) - other consulates will very likely have the same procedure, application form and fees.